# Sprite Kit Collision without bouncing

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics, collision

I setup a hero and some platforms that are moving from the top downwards. 
With these I have collisionBitMasks that detect when the hero lands on a platform if the hero comes from above (to let the hero jump through the platforms)

```
if (_hero.physicsBody.velocity.dy > 0) {
                            _hero.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
                        }
                        else {_hero.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = platformCategory;
                                }
```

Everything works fine, except that the hero keeps bouncing on the platform. 
Is there a way to let him sit on it, while the platform is moving down?

I tried using `physicsBody.resting` and `physicsBody.friction`, but without any success.

Thanks for help Guys

Comment: Really, the answer is just to set **restitution** to zero.  That is SpriteKit's term for "bounciness".  However, you must set both.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up again, jboi's answer should is the way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same issue just a minute ago. It works with setting the `restitution` but you need to set both restitutions. The one of the hero AND the one of the platform (or in my case the scene boundaries).

so:

```
hero.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = platformCategory
hero.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0
platform.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0
any_other_object_that_should_still_bounce.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0
```

will do it. All other objects on the screen still bounce on the platform as long as you set their `restitution > 0`

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to avoid any physics behavior while the hero is on the platform by resetting the hero body's velocity and setting the hero's position to a fixed vertical offset from the platform's position.

In semi-pseudo-code:

```
-(void) didSimulatePhysics
{
    if (<hero on platform>)
    {
        hero.physicsBody.velocity = CGPointZero;
        hero.position = CGPointMake(hero.position.x, 
                                    platform.position.y + <offset as needed>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried altering the restitution property of the nodes' physics bodies?

```
_hero.physicsbody.restitution = 0;
```

It controls the bounciness...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Collision category:

When the velocity.dy is < 0 the hero is falling.

```
func collisionWithPlayer(player: SKNode) {
    // 1
    if player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 && (player.position.y - player.frame.size.height / 2.0) >= (self.position.y){
        // 2
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionCategoryBitMask.Platform

    }
```